# Google Maps JavaScript API V3 - Unload / Deconstructor / Delete / Remove

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I can't find any way to remove and clean up a Google map when using the V3 API.

I've got it running in an AJAX site so I want to kill it off completely without the page having to be reloaded.

I was hoping for a `.unload()` or `.deconstruct()` method, but can't seem to find one.

Any thoughts?

Comment: There is no such thing. V2 had `GUnload()`. Did you think about loading map into the iframe?

Comment: Interesting idea, using it via an iframe would make cleaning it up nice and easy. It would mean reworking some of my website's controls though. Will certainly do this if I run out of other options! Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The V3 API should do a much better job managing it's memory.  Does simply destroying the div that holds the map not meet your needs?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I remove the div that contained the Google map using jQuery's remove() method and I also remove the variable that holds the instance of the map, but still experience slow down on separate pages after visiting the map page - most noticeably on the iPad. NB: I'm afraid I can't post any code right now but might be able to in a week or so!

Comment: Looks like you were right Bamnet, due to a separate bug I wasn't actually removing the div containing the Google map on iOS. The process of working this out did teach me something very useful though - you can bring up a debug console on Safari iOS, it's under settings>Safari>Advanced>Debug console. I would have never found the bug without that! Hopefully that'll help someone else in the future. Thanks for everyone's help.